# sending email with codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, email

I have this **MODEL** and I get the email which I want to send

```
class Cliente_Model extends CI_Model{

public function getInfo($id){

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('pendientes');

    $query = $this->db->get();        

    if($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
        {
            return $row['email'];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
}
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
$this->load->model('cliente_model', 'client');


$clientInfo = $this->client->getInfo($id);      

$this->email->from('myemail@gmail.com', 'Demo'); 
$this->email->to($clientInfo);  

$this->email->subject('Email Test'); 
$this->email->message('your user is '.$clientInfo.' and your password is '.$clave);   

$this->email->send();
```

and I need some help here, I can get the email and it can send it perfectly but in the message I need to send the password also and I don't know how I can get it from the model.

thanks in advance!

Comment: do you want to send email to one user or more that one user ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning '$row['email]' from your model, you should return the whole '$row' which will enable you to get other data from the model and not only the email field.

Not sure, but you might need to use it like this in the controller:

```
$this->email->message('your user is '.$clientInfo->email.' and your password is '.$clientInfo->passwordField);
```

Good luck.

Comment: glad it helped! if it worked, you can approve the answer by accepting it. :) @Maru